Can I replace breakers to connect a generator to my panel?
Here are photos of my box and the receptacle that the breaker is hooked to. Will my electric service panel handle the 50 amp breaker? Also, if it can, does it matter where the breaker goes?



You must use a "generator interlock" which assures the utility breaker must be off before the generator breaker can be turned on.  This is mandatory, it's not skippable.
The particular "generator interlock" will require you to put the generator breaker in a specific place. Move other breakers as needed.
That NEMA 6-15 receptacle in your photo is for a window A/C, or EV charging (hey they had EVs from 1880-1920 LOL).  It is useless for a generator. It can't be changed to an inlet because it doesn't have neutral and is only #14 cable - too little for a 50a generator!
You will need a "generator inlet" which is a socket but with prongs sticking out instead of slots. It is impossible to get zapped because if this breaker is turned on, the utility breaker must be off thanks to the interlock.
For a 50A generator/circuit you will need a 50A generator inlet - probably a twist-lock type depending

Your neutral bus and main lugs are rusty, your ground bus seems to have not enough capacity for what's in the panel and the whole panel is in bad and rusty condition so I don't know if it can withstand the amount of work you'll need to do to install the generator. I don't have the experience to know how an installation in such a beaten up panel might go.  I guess the main bus bars are in similar shape to all the other steel parts here.
You should ask a separate question about how urgently you need to repair your panel and whether certain issues can be grandfathered in to a generator install.   Once you have that squared away you can come back here and then:

It's a 150A main breaker and you want to put in a 50A generator.  That much is ok.
It matters where it goes. It has to go in locations 1 and 3, on the left directly below the main breaker.  You have to move everything else down the bus, or if the wires are long enough you can just move those 4 mini breakers down to the bottom.
You have to install an interlock kit and that has to be adjacent to the main breaker.
The generator needs connections to your ground and neutral bus, both of which need some upgrading.
[ I assumed this but for the avoidance of doubt ] you have to install a new suitable feeder wire to the outside and a 50A inlet there.  This is a bit tricker with a flush panel.


OP will need an inlet, too. If the receptacle is the one he's plugging the generator into, he's using a suicide cable.

@Triplefault it's a 15A outlet.  I assume OP is deleting it and installing a new 50A breaker in that space, a new feed cable and an inlet.   The existing wires to the old location could be used to put a 120V outlet there on another existing breaker or abandoned.  My assumption may be wrong; I hope not.

@jay613 No, it's a 20A receptacle. You can tell from the T-shaped left slot and the "20A" embossed in the face.

@nobody oh dear I didn't click on the photo to see that much detail. It looked like a 6-15 on my tiny screen.  So you're right, but still ... I don't think OP was planning to plug a generator into it.
